# ffmpeg transcode ONLY if downsampling

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, subsonic

I'm using Airsonic as a home music server. It has ffmpeg transcoding capabilities. I'd like to transcode audio ONLY IF input stream has higher parameters (any of `kb/s`, `bit`, `kHz`). And leave native quality if file has lower params (so not to UPscale). Is it possible using some of the `ffmpeg` options?

*P.S. Airsonic has some `Downsample` field, but it doesn't seem to work at all.*

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible with the CLI only.  I usually use a combination of `ffprobe` and some scripting to determine what I need to actually run with FFmpeg.